# Team explorer - Always expand changes frames

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

**Background**

All changes, included and excluded respectively, start out displayed within a framed window, limiting your view on what items are (immediately) visible.

**Out of the box behaviour**

These framed windows seem to expand and collapse dynamically based on what you click on. I.e., they seem to open and close as they see fit, not necessarily as I would expect it.

**Question**

> Is there a way to configure these frames to always remain expanded?

I mean the frames themselves, not the panels they are in, these should collapse/expand as normal:

[image]

So, if I open `the Excluded Changes (78)` panel, I want to be able to see all changes at once (I'd have to scroll, ofcourse).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such settings to auto expand all files directly in Team Explorer.

However, there are two kind of views to show the files in Team Explorer. The **default is tree view** and another is **list view**. You can change to the list view to see all changes at once.

Click the view options and choose *Switch to List View*

[image]

Moreover you can set some filters as you wish to view the changes by select *show filter*.